# JScrollPane won't scroll whole div? -- JScrollPane won't move dynamically with div on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jscrollpane

I am using JScrollPane on a div in order to scroll through it. The div contains a self wrote javascript code that fetches the last couple of posts from my tumblr feed. However, even though the scrollpane is showing fine, for some reason it doesn't scroll completely through the div. This means that when I scroll to the end of the jscroll, there is still more content below the viewable area of the div that is not showing up. I was wondering if anyone could help me figure this out..
Here's the link to the page that I am I working with:
http://prisingh.com/#recent

This is in the head part of the document:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode">
        $(function()
        {
            $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
        });
</script>
```

This is in the body part:

```
<div class="tumblr scroll-pane">
    <img src="images/recenttumblr.png" style="position:fixed;">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tumblr.js"></script>
</div>
```

Here are the javascript codes that are being used:
http://www.prisingh.com/js/

EDIT: now that I have a fix for the original div load problem I was wondering how I would go about having the Jscrollpane move dynamically with the div on window resize. Everytime I resize the window, the JScrollpane remains at the same place it was in when the website was originally loaded. I have tried the code that was given with the plugin:

```
$(function()
{
$('.scroll-pane').each(
    function()
    {
        $(this).jScrollPane(
            {
                showArrows: $(this).is('.arrow')
            }
        );
        var api = $(this).data('jsp');
        var throttleTimeout;
        $(window).bind(
            'resize',
            function()
            {
                if (!throttleTimeout) {
                    throttleTimeout = setTimeout(
                        function()
                        {
                            api.reinitialise();
                            throttleTimeout = null;
                        },
                        50
                    );
                }
            }
        );
    }
)

});
```

This has not solved the problem, the scroll bar keeps the div at the same width it was at on the original loading of the website.
For a demonstration just visit prisingh.com/#recent and try resizing the window once the page is loaded.

Comment: may be the scrollpane is loaded before the image loaded fully !

Comment: @rynhe How would I go about doing this? I tried moving the javascript lower on the page and out of the header, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: share ur html & jquery code

Comment: i will post the answer soon

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $images = $(".tumblr img")
    , imageCount = $images.length
    , counter = 0;
    $images.one("load",function(){
         counter++;
         if (counter == imageCount) {
             $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
         } 
    }).each(function () {
        if (this.complete) {
            $(this).trigger("load");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This helped thanks! Will it work even if videos and text posts are embedded into the tumblr javascript?

Comment: Do you know how I would edit the code so that when I resize the window that the webpage loads in, the jscrollpane is dynamic? NOTHING is working for me :(

Comment: u have to resize the jscrollpane on window resize

Comment: I updated my question if you could help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: post ur question as separate !!!! if i can't to help you,some other will help u...I will try my level best